# Can student data in Blackboard Academic Suite be liberated?

Tags: export

Is it possible for a student of an educational institution that uses Blackboard Academic Suite to download all of the course data to have a personal record of it?  I have an account that is going to expire and would like to download all of the data including documents, gradebooks, discussion boards, and more, but it is extremely cumbersome to do that by hand, and there is no export feature.  Is it possible to get such an archive of one's user data and has anyone ever done it before?

Comment: Ugh, blackboard. Excellent question; I've tried to do the same before and found that getting stuff out of blackboard is downright agonizing.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know the question belonged in a different forum. Anyway, I need a way to do this because otherwise I'll lose all of that data forever.  Why are web applications so bad at accommodating user download of their own data?

Comment: @user553702 so true, it should not be hard - especially when the student does not have the option to choose the application.  All I can say is to try to contact the head of the online learning management systems at the school.  You might find a kindred spirit who might be able to extract and provide the data to you.  Also, you should look into the various interchange formats for Learning Management Systems - for example: Check out this company, the founder is very dedicated to data interchange for LMS systems http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/one-minute-scorm-overview/

Comment: One other suggestion - be diligent about keeping a local copy of your contributed content.  Be organized as possible.  This is likely the best current option.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say so but it is not possible. They have a lot of security features which prevents users from downloading the content.

You can view the content and manually take screenshot, and save each page separately - which is not practical at all.

This kind of security is used so that their content does not gets distributed for free on internet/CDs/pendrives.